# can not connect to internet via bridge adapter in virtual box

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I'm trying to access my ubuntu server which is installed on virtual box using ssh, but ubuntu dose not detect wireless interface.
here is my settings on the server:

[output of ifconfig command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBI5c.png)

[ubuntu setting on virtual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGAGg.png)

[interfaces & *.yaml & sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmn1b.png)

on the client side:

```
$ssh mohammad@192.168.43.161
ssh: connect to host 192.168.43.161 port 22: connection timed out
```

---

openssh-server and openssh-client is installed and running on both machines.

Comment: It seems to detect your wireless adapter, else you couldn't select it in your VM bridged network config. Is your adapter PCI or USB? Did you open port 22 in your firewall? Did you setup /etc/netplan/*.yaml for the wireless adapter? Do you really wish to SSH over wireless vs ethernet?

Comment: Change your VM network config to use the Realtek.

Comment: @heynnema I'm new to these king of things. I want to SSH to my server over wireless. can you tell me what should I do step by step please?

Comment: SSH over ethernet would be more reliable. If you use wireless in your VM, the wireless adapter won't be available to your host. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Install `gufw` and enable your firewall, but open port 22.

Comment: @heynnema I did what you said. also I'v already tried SSH over ethernet and it's working.

Comment: Problem solved then?

Comment: @heynnema so you are telling it's not possible SSH to a server over wireless while the server is in virtual box?

Comment: You can define a second network path that goes to the wireless, but you'll have to connect to the network manually I believe. Don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to connect guest over bridge connection because both system use  same port 22 for ssh. I would suggest to configure port forwarding 2222 (or any unused/reserved) port on host to 22 port on guest system.  After configuring port forwarding you will be able to connect to your guest system over 2222 port (or any unused/reserved port).

```
ssh user@192.168.43.168 (or any ip of guest system) -p 2222
```